# Web API error response Id

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an error response model in my API project:

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string ErrorId { get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
}
```

I need to generate a random ErrorId. I saw the use of Random class but just wondering what is the best way to do this. Some consideration, do I need to create the ErrorId in the constructor of ErrorResponse class and make ErrorId as read-only (no setter) or do I let the ErrorId set by the calling class.

Comment: Well it's a string data type -  you may want to change that. And it all depends on how you're using it. If you aren't persisting the errors anywhere or using logging, I almost don't see the point in asking your question.

Comment: It is not getting persisted to database. The errorId is for reference. A use case is if our API clients gets an error, they can report the error and report the errorId. We can check then in our log for that errorId and verify the detailed error message. The API client will in some errors will just get the generic error but having the errorId that they can report, we can verify in our log the actual/detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) class or generate a [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx). But I just want to expand on what I think you are trying to do. Instead of your own custom error response - perhaps considering using the [HttpResponseException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception(v=vs.118).aspx) or the [HttpResponseMesssage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx). You can include a custom / random error identifier in Content / reason or in the message.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            SomeMethod();

            return new string[] { "xxx", "yyy" };

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                                            {
                                                Content = new StringContent("An error occurred."),
                                                ReasonPhrase = "your custom error id"
                                            });

           // log
        }
    }
```

And:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)  
    {  
      try  
      {  
         // your code
      }  
      catch (Exception ex)  
      {  
         // Log exception code goes here  
         return  Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "your custom error id.”);  
      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `Guid` and assign it to ErrorId in the constructor:

```
public ErrorResponse()
{
    ErrorId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to give the client an http response and include the ErrorId:

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "ErrorId");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to create Random number is to use Random class in C#... Here is the example

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int first = rnd.Next(1, 40); //Number between 1(inclusive) and 40(exclusive)
int second = rnd.Next(10);     //Number between 0 and 9
```

**Note**: If you are going to create more than one random numbers then you should use the same instance of the Random class. If you create new instance too close in time, there are chances that they both will produce the same random numbers as Random class is based(seeded)on System clock.

Answer (score 0):

I use Random but quite not sure if there are consequences in an API application(due to thread-safety, etc). So in the constructor, I generate the ErrorId.

```
public ErrorResponse()
{
    var random = new Random();
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890.!+-?";
    ErrorId = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 10)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```